# Receive socket request, pass through various endpoints, and Respond back to same socket connection using netty in camel

Tags: sockets, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I am currently using netty in custom camel components to listen on a socket (Using a consumer with netty channel handlers), pass the message from the socket to multiple camel endpoints and ultimately write out the final result in a flat file.

This works fine, but it is obviously limited to "in only" functionality.

What I'd like to do is, instead of writing the final result to a flat file, send that final result back to the requester through the socket.

Something like this does not work.. Pseudocode:

```
<route>
  <from:netty:tcp://localhost:1111/>
  <to:endpoint1/>
</route>
<route>
  <from:endpoint1 />
  <to:netty:tcp://localhost:1111 />
</route>
```

What I suspect is happening is that my use of

```
<to:netty:tcp://localhost:1111 />
```

is causing the NettyProducer to try to establish a new connection to a server at localhost:1111, which doesn't exist since it is a socket client.  Instead of magically using the channels opened by the consumer that I want it to.  Is this just a matter of setting the proper uri options or is this not possible?

That's the high level description of the problem.  Here is some more details on my assumptions and what I'd like if the above wasn't clear enough.

From what I understand, camel-netty has a NettyConsumer that creates a socket server that will listen on a socket.  Also, it has a NettyProducer that creates a socket client that will write to a socket.

My question is: Can I configure the NettyConsumer and NettyProducer to use the same socket/channel?  I'd assume that in order for this to be possible the netty pipeline/channels/or some component knowledgable of the connection would need to be shared on the Endpoint level since it is common to both the Consumer and the Producer.

I've read the documentation regarding synchronous request-response but I believe this only applies when you have a single processor that consumes the exchange body and sends it back through the exchange.

My not so great interim solution:

So I actually got this working but I'm not in love with it.  Here is what I did:

- Create/Extend a SimpleChannelHandler that simply blocks/polls for the destination file
- Add this handler as my last handler in the server pipeline
- Once my other endpoint processes have completed and the file is created, the polling handler pulls the contents of the file and writes the contents downstream and closes the channel.
- The response ultimately gets back to the original socket client.

I tested this with a plain socket client and works.  Even though this works, it feels somewhat like a hack and I'd much rather configure a camel producer to send the response back to the client.

At this point, I need to know if I can do this or if I need to write something more customized for myself.  The only requirement is camel and socket io, if netty can't do this and something else can, that would help too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use `<from:netty:tcp://localhost:1111?sync=true/>`, then enrich the exchange and leave it to camel to send back the exchange body via the socket connection, or have you jumped directly to your workaround solution? I have not worked with the netty component before, but the doc reads like what you want should "just work".

Comment: Ralf, yes I have tried this and it does work but it does not allow me to send the exchange off to another endpoint.  Using sync=true, you enrich the exchange but don't set a <to:..> and the exchange will ultimately get sent back through the requesting socket channel.

Comment: So you want to receive data on Socket IP1:PORT1, enrich the message and then send it off to a 3rd entity reachable on IP2:PORT2? I thought your 3rd bullet point meant to send back the response to the original caller.

Comment: No, that is not what I want.  I want to receive data on Socket IP1:PORT1, enrich the message by routing the exchange to various  endpoints (while keeping the connection on Socket IP1:PORT1 open) and ultimately send back the final message back to Socket IP1:PORT1.  To the socket client, this would just appear to be a typical request-response.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
<camel:route id="rest.route.request.search">
    <from:netty:tcp://localhost:1111/>
    <!-- Send exchange off to another endpoint for enrichment/processing -->
    <camel:enrich ref="some.endpoint.ref" />
    <!-- Exchange body is sent back to caller -->
</camel:route>
```

With the [content enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) you should be able to route the exchange via an arbitrary number of endpoints and let Camel send the exchange body back via the socket connection on which you received the request.

Comment: Thanks Ralf.  I believe this is what I was looking for.  I'm new to camel and just read up on content enrichment.  I believe I should be able to use the enrich DSL or pipeline a few processors to get what I want.  I think the problem was that I had a misconception that I needed to send an exchange to a new route everytime I enriched/transformed it once.